# Compare column value with series of auto sum value in Power Pivot?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have problem where i need to get the number of weeks after which my stock will run-out.
In my table i have:

- "Forecast Regulier calc." which is the total sales.
- And the auto generated total is the project stock.

Each value of "Forecast Regulier calc." in column is the sales on that particular week. Now the goal is to compare the sales of each week with the series of all auto generated total values and get the difference in column values where the two values match. And this will be the number of weeks after which our stock will run-out.

*Please let me know if the description is not clear.*

[image: Screenshot of data].

Comment: Unfortunatley "I want" is not a valid question here on SO. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: @JvdV is it any better now?